# Not getting the correct output through procedure execution

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am writing one recursive procedure for the below table(sample_table):
Consider each column has varchar2 datatype:

```
PARENT_DATA CHILD_DATA  PARENT_VERSION  CHILD_VERSION
----------------------------------------------------------------
20-10       40-01       -A11            -A11
20-10       40-02       -A11            -A11
20-10       40-03       -A11            -A11
20-10       80-10       -A11            -A11
20-10       81-10       -A11            -A11
80-10       40-100      -A11            -A11
80-10       40-101      -A11            -A11
80-10       40-102      -A11            -A11
```

I need to write a recursive procedure such that for the given PARENT_DATA, if CHILD_DATA starts with '40' then it will be printed.
If the CHILD_DATA starts with '80' then the procedure will be called recursively. 
The final output will be as shown below:

```
PARENT_DATA CHILD_DATA PARENT_VERSION CHILD_VERSION
---------------------------------------------------
20-10       40-01       -A11        -A11
20-10       40-02       -A11        -A11
20-10       40-03       -A11        -A11
80-10       40-100      -A11        -A11
80-10       40-101      -A11        -A11
80-10       40-102      -A11        -A11
```

I have tried with the recursive procedure call with cursor:

This is the code:

```
create or replace procedure proc_repeat(in_parent         in  varchar2,
                                        IN_VERSION        IN  VARCHAR2,
                                        out_child         out varchar2,
                                        OUT_CHILD_VERSION OUT VARCHAR2)
as
  v_parent_Data varchar2(50);
  v_data varchar2(50);
  v_data_VERSION varchar2(50);
  v_data_RECUR varchar2(50);
  v_data_RECUR_VERSION varchar2(50);

  cursor cur_data is 
    select parent_data,child_data,child_version
      from sample_table
      where parent_data = in_parent AND
            parent_version = IN_VERSION;
begin
  open cur_data;
  loop
    fetch cur_data
      into v_parent_Data,v_data,v_data_VERSION;

    exit when cur_data%notfound;

    IF V_DATA LIKE '40-%' THEN
      OUT_CHILD:=V_DATA;
      OUT_CHILD_VERSION:=v_data_VERSION;
    ELSIF V_DATA LIKE '80-%' THEN
      v_data_RECUR:=V_DATA;
      v_data_RECUR_VERSION:=v_data_VERSION;

      proc_repeat(v_data_RECUR, v_data_RECUR_VERSION,
                  out_child, OUT_CHILD_VERSION);
    END IF;
  end loop;

  close cur_Data;
end;
```

The expected result is:

```
CHILD_DATA
-----------
40-01
40-02
40-03
40-100
40-101
40-102
```

But I am getting only '40-102'

```
DECLARE
  A VARCHAR2(50):='20-10';
  B VARCHAR2(50):='-A11';
  C VARCHAR2(50);
  D VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  proc_repeat(A,B,C,D);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(C);
END;
```

Comment: The only time you print anything is in the anonymous block which makes the first call to your procedure, so of course only a single line is output. Perhaps you need to print something from inside the procedure as well.

Comment: So what is the possible way to get the expected output?

Comment: Call `dbms_output` in the procedure. It's a bit hard to tell exactly where from reading it. What is the output for, though? Is your question how to add debug messages in general?

Comment: You input `20-10` as argument for `in_parent` but want to get results with `80-10`

Answer (score 0):

Let's create an instrumented version of your procedure by adding some DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE calls. This will look like:

```
create or replace procedure proc_repeat_I1(in_parent         in  varchar2,
                                           IN_VERSION        IN  VARCHAR2,
                                           out_child         out varchar2,
                                           OUT_CHILD_VERSION OUT VARCHAR2)
as
  v_parent_Data varchar2(50);
  v_data varchar2(50);
  v_data_VERSION varchar2(50);
  v_data_RECUR varchar2(50);
  v_data_RECUR_VERSION varchar2(50);

  cursor cur_data is 
    select parent_data,child_data,child_version
      from sample_table
      where parent_data = in_parent AND
            parent_version = IN_VERSION;
begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROC_REPEAT_I1 : START - IN_PARENT=' || IN_PARENT ||
                                    ' IN_VERSION=' || IN_VERSION ||
                                    ' OUT_CHILD=' || OUT_CHILD);

  open cur_data;
  loop
    fetch cur_data
      into v_parent_Data,v_data,v_data_VERSION;

    exit when cur_data%notfound;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROC_REPEAT_I1 : v_parent_Data=' || v_parent_Data ||
                                      ' v_data=' || v_data);

    IF V_DATA LIKE '40-%' THEN
      OUT_CHILD:=V_DATA;
      OUT_CHILD_VERSION:=v_data_VERSION;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROC_REPEAT_I1 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = ' || OUT_CHILD);
    ELSIF V_DATA LIKE '80-%' THEN
      v_data_RECUR:=V_DATA;
      v_data_RECUR_VERSION:=v_data_VERSION;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROC_REPEAT_I1 : BLOCK 2 : OUT_CHILD = ' || OUT_CHILD ||
                           ' V_DATA_RECUR = ' || V_DATA_RECUR);

      proc_repeat_I(v_data_RECUR, v_data_RECUR_VERSION,
                    out_child, OUT_CHILD_VERSION);
    END IF;
  end loop;

  close cur_Data;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROC_REPEAT_I1 : EXIT');
end;
```

When we run this, the output is:

```
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : START - IN_PARENT=20-10 IN_VERSION=-A11 OUT_CHILD=
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : v_parent_Data=20-10 v_data=40-01
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-01
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : v_parent_Data=20-10 v_data=40-02
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-02
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : v_parent_Data=20-10 v_data=40-03
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-03
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : v_parent_Data=20-10 v_data=80-10
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : BLOCK 2 : OUT_CHILD = 40-03 V_DATA_RECUR = 80-10
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : START - IN_PARENT=80-10 IN_VERSION=-A11 OUT_CHILD=
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : v_parent_Data=80-10 v_data=40-100
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-100
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : v_parent_Data=80-10 v_data=40-101
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-101
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : v_parent_Data=80-10 v_data=40-102
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-102
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : EXIT
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : v_parent_Data=20-10 v_data=81-10
PROC_REPEAT_I1 : EXIT
40-102
```

We can see that the first call to the procedure from the anonymous block is made, passing `'20-10'` as the parent and `'-A11'` as the parent version, and the cursor then iterates through `'40-01`', `'40-02'`, and `'40-03'` until it gets to `'80-10'`. Once it gets to `'80-20'` it goes to the second block and calls itself recursively, then iterates through `'40-100'`, `'40-101'`, and `'40-102'` as expected.

So what's wrong here? Well, nothing - except that nowhere does your code cause the value from the cursor to be either accumulated into `OUT_CHILD`, or printed. So let's change our instrumented version to accumulate the values returned from the cursor into `OUT_CHILD`:

```
create or replace procedure proc_repeat_I2(in_parent         in  varchar2,
                                           IN_VERSION        IN  VARCHAR2,
                                           out_child         out varchar2,
                                           OUT_CHILD_VERSION OUT VARCHAR2)
as
  v_parent_Data varchar2(50);
  v_data varchar2(50);
  v_data_VERSION varchar2(50);
  v_data_RECUR varchar2(50);
  v_data_RECUR_VERSION varchar2(50);

  cursor cur_data is 
    select parent_data,child_data,child_version
      from sample_table
      where parent_data = in_parent AND
            parent_version = IN_VERSION;
begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROC_REPEAT : START - IN_PARENT=' || IN_PARENT ||
                                    ' IN_VERSION=' || IN_VERSION ||
                                    ' OUT_CHILD=' || OUT_CHILD);

  open cur_data;
  loop
    fetch cur_data
      into v_parent_Data,v_data,v_data_VERSION;

    exit when cur_data%notfound;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROC_REPEAT : v_parent_Data=' || v_parent_Data ||
                                      ' v_data=' || v_data);

    IF V_DATA LIKE '40-%' THEN
      OUT_CHILD := CASE
                     WHEN OUT_CHILD IS NULL THEN OUT_CHILD
                     ELSE OUT_CHILD || ', '
                   END || V_DATA;
      OUT_CHILD_VERSION := CASE
                             WHEN OUT_CHILD_VERSION IS NULL THEN OUT_CHILD_VERSION
                             ELSE OUT_CHILD_VERSION || ', '
                           END || V_DATA_VERSION;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = ' || OUT_CHILD);
    ELSIF V_DATA LIKE '80-%' THEN
      v_data_RECUR:=V_DATA;
      v_data_RECUR_VERSION:=v_data_VERSION;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('BLOCK 2 : OUT_CHILD = ' || OUT_CHILD ||
                           ' V_DATA_RECUR = ' || V_DATA_RECUR);

      proc_repeat_I2(v_data_RECUR, v_data_RECUR_VERSION,
                     out_child, OUT_CHILD_VERSION);
    END IF;
  end loop;

  close cur_Data;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROC_REPEAT : EXIT');
end;
```

But this *still* doesn't get it right! Here's the output:

```
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : START - IN_PARENT=20-10 IN_VERSION=-A11 OUT_CHILD=
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : v_parent_Data=20-10 v_data=40-01
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-01
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : v_parent_Data=20-10 v_data=40-02
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-01, 40-02
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : v_parent_Data=20-10 v_data=40-03
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-01, 40-02, 40-03
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : v_parent_Data=20-10 v_data=80-10
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : BLOCK 2 : OUT_CHILD = 40-01, 40-02, 40-03 V_DATA_RECUR = 80-10
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : START - IN_PARENT=80-10 IN_VERSION=-A11 OUT_CHILD=
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : v_parent_Data=80-10 v_data=40-100
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-100
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : v_parent_Data=80-10 v_data=40-101
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-100, 40-101
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : v_parent_Data=80-10 v_data=40-102
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-100, 40-101, 40-102
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : EXIT
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : v_parent_Data=20-10 v_data=81-10
PROC_REPEAT_I2 : EXIT
40-100, 40-101, 40-102
```

Here we can see that the parent values seem to be getting accumulated until we go into block 2 and make the recursive call to PROC_REPEAT_I2, at which point...THEY VANISH! AGGGHHHH! WHAT HAPPENED?!?!?!?

Well, interesting fact about PL/SQL - when you call a routine with an `OUT` parameter, the OUT parameter is set to NULL at the beginning of the procedure. If you want the value which is already in the procedure argument to be retained you need to define the argument as `IN OUT` instead of `OUT`. So we get our third version of this procedure:

```
create or replace procedure PROC_REPEAT_I3(in_parent         in  varchar2,
                                           IN_VERSION        IN  VARCHAR2,
                                           out_child         IN OUT varchar2,
                                           OUT_CHILD_VERSION IN OUT VARCHAR2)
as
  v_parent_Data varchar2(50);
  v_data varchar2(50);
  v_data_VERSION varchar2(50);
  v_data_RECUR varchar2(50);
  v_data_RECUR_VERSION varchar2(50);

  cursor cur_data is 
    select parent_data,child_data,child_version
      from sample_table
      where parent_data = in_parent AND
            parent_version = IN_VERSION;
begin
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROC_REPEAT_I3 : START - IN_PARENT=' || IN_PARENT ||
                                    ' IN_VERSION=' || IN_VERSION ||
                                    ' OUT_CHILD=' || OUT_CHILD);

  open cur_data;
  loop
    fetch cur_data
      into v_parent_Data,v_data,v_data_VERSION;

    exit when cur_data%notfound;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROC_REPEAT_I3 : v_parent_Data=' || v_parent_Data ||
                                      ' v_data=' || v_data);

    IF V_DATA LIKE '40-%' THEN
      OUT_CHILD := CASE
                     WHEN OUT_CHILD IS NULL THEN OUT_CHILD
                     ELSE OUT_CHILD || ', '
                   END || V_DATA;
      OUT_CHILD_VERSION := CASE
                             WHEN OUT_CHILD_VERSION IS NULL THEN OUT_CHILD_VERSION
                             ELSE OUT_CHILD_VERSION || ', '
                           END || V_DATA_VERSION;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROC_REPEAT_I3 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = ' || OUT_CHILD);
    ELSIF V_DATA LIKE '80-%' THEN
      v_data_RECUR:=V_DATA;
      v_data_RECUR_VERSION:=v_data_VERSION;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROC_REPEAT_I3 : BLOCK 2 : OUT_CHILD = ' || OUT_CHILD ||
                           ' V_DATA_RECUR = ' || V_DATA_RECUR);

      proc_repeat_I3(v_data_RECUR, v_data_RECUR_VERSION,
                  out_child, OUT_CHILD_VERSION);
    END IF;
  end loop;

  close cur_Data;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROC_REPEAT_I3 : EXIT');
end;
```

and the output from this version looks like:

```
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : START - IN_PARENT=20-10 IN_VERSION=-A11 OUT_CHILD=
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : v_parent_Data=20-10 v_data=40-01
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-01
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : v_parent_Data=20-10 v_data=40-02
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-01, 40-02
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : v_parent_Data=20-10 v_data=40-03
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-01, 40-02, 40-03
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : v_parent_Data=20-10 v_data=80-10
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : BLOCK 2 : OUT_CHILD = 40-01, 40-02, 40-03 V_DATA_RECUR = 80-10
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : START - IN_PARENT=80-10 IN_VERSION=-A11 OUT_CHILD=40-01, 40-02, 40-03
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : v_parent_Data=80-10 v_data=40-100
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-01, 40-02, 40-03, 40-100
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : v_parent_Data=80-10 v_data=40-101
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-01, 40-02, 40-03, 40-100, 40-101
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : v_parent_Data=80-10 v_data=40-102
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : BLOCK 1 : OUT_CHILD = 40-01, 40-02, 40-03, 40-100, 40-101, 40-102
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : EXIT
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : v_parent_Data=20-10 v_data=81-10
PROC_REPEAT_I3 : EXIT
40-01, 40-02, 40-03, 40-100, 40-101, 40-102
```

Finally, the correct results are produced.

So, remember - when things don't work try printing out the intermediate results so you can see what's going on.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a18081637193b0b9ad05389707e8f370)